# List with wrapped figures

Tags: lists, wrap

I am trying to define a list to describe a series of images. I would like each list element to have the image aligned with the first line of the description text and have the text wrap around the image.

My attempt is listed below, but two issues remain:

1. I would like "Step XX:" no to stick out into the margin (the rest of the text should be indented).
2. The wrapping fails for short paragraphs or when the description for an item has multiple paragraphs, see Step 2 in the example.

Here is the code. Any suggestions on solving the two issues above is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcounter{step}
\newenvironment{steps}%
    {\par\setcounter{step}{0}}%
    {\par\bigskip}%
\newlength{\stepmargin}%
\setlength{\stepmargin}{1em}%
\newlength{\windowwidth}%
\setlength{\windowwidth}{\textwidth}%
\addtolength{\windowwidth}{-5cm}%
\addtolength{\windowwidth}{-\stepmargin}%

\newcommand\step[2]{%
    \stepcounter{step}%
    \begingroup
    \opencutright
    \pageinwindow 
    \renewcommand\windowpagestuff{%
        \hspace*{\stepmargin}%
        \includegraphics[%
            width=5cm,
            height=8\baselineskip,
            keepaspectratio]{#1}%
        }%
    \leftmargin=1.5cm\begin{cutout}{0}{\windowwidth}{0pt}{9}%
        \noindent
        \llap{%
            \makebox[1.5cm][l]{%
                \bfseries
                Step~\arabic{step}:%
            }%
        }%
    #2%
    \end{cutout}%
    \endgroup
    \par\bigskip
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{steps}
    \step{step1.png}{\lipsum[2]}
    \step{step2.png}{%
        Short description that doesen't take up the total height of the image.\par 
        The text might have paragraphs.\par
        The next step should start below the image for this step.
    }
    \step{step3.png}{\lipsum[3]}
\end{steps}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```